# iPad split view dimension parts

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app that needs backgrounds for both parts of the split view.

If the whole screen is `1024 x 768`, what is the size of each part?

left : w:xx px ;  h: 768px
right: w:xx px ;  h: 768px

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The split view's master is 320 px wide according to the documentation, leaving the detail pane a comfortable 768 or 704 px wide depending on the orientation of the device.

Comment: Please let me know if I am working with UISplitviewcontroller  for all orientation then how to decide xib height width mode for design without Autolayout.