# Why view size is 703x768 for iPad app in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, ipad-2

Im working on my first iPad app.
By default Xcode generated for me a starting point project, which contains the basic template for the Split view controller.

I am focusing on the detail view controller right now (my first app version may only utilize this view).

Anyway, I noticed that in the Xcode integrated Interface Builder the detail view is 703 (width) x 768 (height).

First question: why is the width 703?

Now, the view in the IB shows a portrait layout of the view. So it's even more odd that the width is greater than the height (when it should be the other way around).

I actually expected the width to be 768, and the height 1024.

- updated *

2nd Question: In portrait mode, why is the width 1024 and height 768 (see above closing comments).

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004771/ipad-split-view-dimension-parts

Comment: that is definitely the answer ive been looking for. duh. if you "answer" this question i will mark it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split view's master is 320 px wide according to the documentation, leaving the detail pane a comfortable 768 or 704 px wide depending on the orientation of the device.

ref> [ipad split view dimension parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004771/ipad-split-view-dimension-parts)

Please take a look [here](http://vickiwenderlich.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Basics_ipad1.jpg)

Comment: Hey thanks. If you can answer the 2nd question, ill consider this satisfactorily answered!

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar I have added a link.. hope it helps

Comment: @Kenpachi your link is now broken. Could you please attach a new one?